# Is flying a drone in Puerto Rico the same as flying one in the continental USA?

Tags: regulations, faa, puerto-rico

Puerto Rico, a US territory in the Caribbean, is under the jurisdiction of the USA but is exempt from some of its laws - for example, it is considered within the USA under immigration law (e.g. the requirements to enter are the same as the mainland USA, flights between Puerto Rico and the mainland are considered domestic, etc.) but is considered overseas for Federal tax purposes (residents are exempt from many Federal taxes).

Are drones in Puerto Rico regulated under the same FAA rules as the rest of the USA, or are there different rules to follow (e.g. different licenses, fewer or additional prohibitions, etc.) that would not be typical of a US State?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about legal issues which seems to be off-topic for the site.

Comment: I think this one is on topic, regardless of the outcome of the legal/regulation question discussion, as it is essentially asking "Whose rules should I be looking at", rather than specifics/interpretations of a law.

Comment: I also feel this is on topic. Drone regulations affect all drone pilots. It is very common to find regulation questions in SE.Aviation, they have a specific `FAA-regulations` tag. C.f. https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faa-regulations.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

> The FAA proposed to limit the applicability of part 107 to small UAS operations that are conducted entirely within the United States. [[source]](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2016/06/28/2016-15079/operation-and-certification-of-small-unmanned-aircraft-systems)

Puerto Rico is considered as within the United States.

Comment: You might consider adding that [14 CFR 1.1](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=c141bb3a39c3fa565601fd9a9bf704c3&mc=true&node=se14.1.1_11&rgn=div8)  is where the FAA defines Puerto Rico as being within the United States.